# Downgrading Windows 10 To 7

Tags: windows, laptop

I have asus laptop G551VW-FY212T and windows 10 has a lot of issues, I can't reset windows 10 os it gives me error so I just want to downgrade to windows 7.

How do I downgrade to windows 7? Should I do it though bios or in windows 10?

Now I heard of this Chinese program called "driver genius" which is supposed to download drivers for computer that does not support windows 7. Problem is though it is in Chinese so what other way can I download windows 7 drivers for this laptop?

I have a windows 7 disc to put in my laptop but the track pad and keyboard are unresponsive during windows 7 setup. External mouse keyboard do not work either :(

Comment: Try to boot from a USB. Put a Windows setup copy on an USB and then set bios to boot from usb first.

Comment: "windows 10 has a lot of issues" what issue? "it gives me error" so what's the error

Comment: which issues you have in win10? post more details. Win7 fails, because you need to add USB3 drivers to the boot.wim first

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go back is from a disk image. However, after a length of time using Windows 10, Microsoft may no longer validate the old OS, so reverting to 7 is not a good choice.

[You can download the latest Windows 10 ISO directly from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and use that to either try to upgrade your current Windows 10 installation, or better, do a *complete installation*, wiping out the current OS, which would, of course, wipe out your files, so back them up first.

Another choice would be a Linux distro, such as Ubuntu. Ubuntu can b tested from a USB drive, so you'll be sure all drivers work before actual installation.

I definitely **do not recommend** third-party tools, such as "this Chinese program called driver genius". Windows installation media should have, or be able to download, all drivers needed.